# Retrieve embedded document using Mongo DB filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

```
  Pet: [
    { _id: "pet_id1", moko: "zzzzz", status: "st_id2"},
    { _id: "pet_id2", moko: "eeeeeezasxsdsf", status: "st_id3"},
    { _id: "pet_id3", moko: "aqsz", status: "st_id4" },
    { _id: "pet_id4", moko: "goreefggg", status: "st_id3" },
    { _id: "pet_id5", moko: "zzzzz", status: "st_id2" }
  ],
  PetStatus: [
    { _id: "st_id1", code: 1, petId: "pet_id5" },
    { _id: "st_id2", code: 3, petId: "pet_id1" }
  ]
```

I want to retrieve all documents of Pet Table and for each element, replace status by some object like

```
petModel.find({ $and: [moko: "zzzzz"], ...})
```

Filter result i want :

```
[
    { _id: "pet_id1", moko: "zzzzz", status: { _id: "st_id2",code: 3,petId: "pet_id1"},},
    { _id: "pet_id5", moko: "zzzzz", status: { _id: "st_id2",code: 3, petId: "pet_id1"},},
  ]
```

I found this as solution, it works now:

```
const filter = [
        { $match: { breederId: "zzzzz",},},
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'PetStatus',let: { status_id: '$moko',},
            pipeline: [
              {$match: { $expr: {
                    $and: [
                      {$eq: [3, '$code'],},
                      {$eq: ['$_id', '$$status_id'],},],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            as: 'status',},},
        {$match: {$expr: { $gt: [
                {$size: '$status', }, 0,],},
          },},];
petModel.aggregate(filter);
```

Comment: Please adjust your tags: you currently tagged both `azure-cosmosdb` and `mongodb-atlas`, two completely different services. Also, please edit your question to show the query you attempted, along with issues you're having. Currently you have only shown one sample input document, with nothing else. You should show expected output, actual output, etc.

Comment: You are quite right.... I just updated the question by putting an example input and then the expected output relative to the given example. I hope that. i 'am new to use mongodb. I used `petModel.find({ $and: [moko: "zzzzz"], ...})` that get pets document with moko="zzzzz", and and i have no idea how PetStatus.findBy(foreign key) in the same filter

Comment: I done like: ` const filter.$and = [{ $match: { moko: "zzzzz",}, },
  { $lookup: { from: 'PetStatus',
      let: {status_id: '$status',},pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: {$and: [{$eq:[3, '$code'],},
         { $eq: ['$_id', '$$status_id'],}, ], },}, }, ],
      as: 'status_',
    },
  }, {$match: { $expr: {$gt: [ {$size: '$status_', }, 0,], }, }, }] ;
  PetModel.find(filter).limit(limit).skip(skip).populate(populate.join(' '))` 
i have some error like: `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] unknown top level operator: $match MongoError: unknown top level operator: $match`

Comment: Please *edit your question* and properly format your JSON. As written (as a comment), what you provided is unreadable (no indentation, all on a single line).

Comment: Great that you formatted it correctly - very readable. However, you mentioned that it's a solution and you solved your problem? Solutions *shouldn't* go as edits to your question; they belong as *answers*. Please leave solutions out of questions and create a proper answer (also explain why it worked as an answer, in your answer).